# Webpage stopped responding to external CSS changes

Tags: html, css, mamp

I'm currently working on developing a website on my computer, and I've been very successful at working on my html and external stylesheet for some time. The results don't come out the way I want, but at least the code is doing what I tell it to do.

However, I've been trying to incorportate PHP into my pages and I've since downloaded MAMP to my computer and changed my pages into .php pages so that the php pages I want to include are included. I managed to do all that just fine and yesterday I went back to work on my layout some more.

Suddenly, none of my webpages, either the .php version or the original .html version, are interacting or responding to changes I make in my .css file. It all worked fine before, but now suddenly it wont respond. I've tried turning my MAMP server off, I've tried removing the .css file and then restoring it (thinking somehow it was getting stuck on old code?) and I've tried tweaking the code in the original folder I was working out of. Not that it should matter, and it didn't.

Am I missing something?

When I downloaded MAMP, I had to copy and more my original files to the "htdocs" folder so that my local host could have access to the files. I would understand if there was something wrong there, but it isn't responding in the original files either.

In addition to changes not being acknowledged (or perhaps because of), my navigation bar is responding to code that doesn't exist.

Is there a way to fix this that does not involve starting over?

Comment: Can we see your HTML and the folder structure?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to diagnose with what we have available here. Are you able to see the CSS file by viewing the page source and following the file's link? (Chrome does this best.) Also, "code that doesn't exist" can't do stuff. Yes, you're missing something. :-)

Comment: ``I had to copy and more my original files to the "htdocs" folder so that my local host could have access to the files``. If you copied your files to htdocs, are you sure you're editing the files in the correct folder? Also, what url are you looking at to test this? Is it like ``http://localhost/my-project``?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I closed all my pages and reopened my .php page and my .css page, and there was all this code for the navigation that should have been deleted on previous saves. But now my code is working. Go figure. Perhaps someone could offer why this happened in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize there had been responses. I had triple-checked everything. The source for the .css page (the locations were all relative so moving my files shouldn't have affected that), I checked whether I was working out of my htdocs folder or my original one (but there were no changes taking place anywhere so that doesn't explain anything) and I kept checking over and over if I was on the right file (.php vs .html) and the right .css document. Everything matched. Except my changes to my .css file. . . I wish I knew what happened so I could keep it from happening again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a caching issue.

There are tags you can use that will help. Also make sure your browser cache settings aren't on Automatic, but Every visit to the page.

I have to use all these to try to cover all the bases:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: Thank you TIm. I presume you should add these to the HEAD portion of the code, right? I will add this and hopefully it wont happen again.

Comment: Right, they go in the head anywhere before the <body> tag...and browsers aren't consistent with support for this, thus all the different methods...